# Printing a nested list with formatting

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a Perl function that takes in two Lists/Arrays and computes the cross-product of them(cartesian product). I currently have code working that takes the two input Lists and computes the cross-product, but I having trouble printing the nested Lists.

I am looking for advice on the *best* way to print a nested List. Here is my current attempt that works:

```
for(@C) { 
    for(@$_) { 
        print $_; 
    } 
    print " ";
}

# prints
# 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 1G 1H 1I 
# 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 2G 2H 2I 
# 3A 3B 3C 3D 3E 3F 3G 3H 3I 
# 4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F 4G 4H 4I 
# etc ...
```

but this didn't look *Perly* enough for me. So I made another attempt with `map`:

```
print map { 
    map { $_ } @$_; 
} @C;

# prints
# 1A1B1C1D1E1F1G1H1I
# 2A2B2C2D2E2F2G2H2I
# 3A3B3C3D3E3F3G3H3I
# 4A4B4C4D4E4F4G4H4I
# etc ...
```

but the items are all pressed together. Is there anyway to format this approach with `map`? Are there better ways of accomplishing this?

Full function code:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

# globals
my @digits  = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
my @letters = ("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I");
my @rows = @digits;
my @cols = @letters;
my @squares = cross(\@rows, \@cols);

sub cross {
    my @C = [];

    foreach (reverse @_) {
        my @A = @$_;

        @C = map { my $n = $_; map { [ $n, @$_ ] } @C } @A;
    }

    # works
    #for(@C) { 
    #   for(@$_) { 
    #       print $_; 
    #   } 
    #   print " ";
    #}

    print map { 
        map { $_ } @$_; 
    } @C;

    return @C;
}
```

Comment: why `map { $_ } @$_`?  How is that any different than just `@$_`?

Comment: @Flimzy `@$_` is an array reference, I want to see the individual elements.

Comment: The `@` de-references the arrayref in `$_`. `map { $_ }` does nothing except needlessly iterate through each of those elements, returning each one, un-altered.

Comment: @Flimzy hmm ok, I am still really new to Perl, so I am not sure what everything does. Thanks for clarifying this for me though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print map { join '', @$_, ' ' } @C;
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing that says `map` can't return formatted strings:

```
print map { " $_" };
```

Or for more precise control, use join:

```
print join ' ', map { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

By default arrays interpolate into strings as you want them here.  So:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;

my @a = ([qw/1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 1G 1H 1I/],
         [qw/2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 2G 2H 2I/],
         [qw/3A 3B 3C 3D 3E 3F 3G 3H 3I/],
         [qw/4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F 4G 4H 4I/],
         ['etc', '...']);

say "# prints";
say "# @$_" for @a;
```

Outputs:

```
# prints
# 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 1G 1H 1I
# 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 2G 2H 2I
# 3A 3B 3C 3D 3E 3F 3G 3H 3I
# 4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F 4G 4H 4I
# etc ...
```

Alternatively,

```
local $" = ', ';
say "# @$_" for @a;
```

Outputs:

```
# 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, 1E, 1F, 1G, 1H, 1I
# 2A, 2B, 2C, 2D, 2E, 2F, 2G, 2H, 2I
# 3A, 3B, 3C, 3D, 3E, 3F, 3G, 3H, 3I
# 4A, 4B, 4C, 4D, 4E, 4F, 4G, 4H, 4I
# etc, ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasn't hardcoding the strings however, I was taking `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)` and `(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I)` and computing the cartesian product to get all of those other strings.

Comment: Could you explain what the first block of code you assign to `@a` does ?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, `([qw/a b c/], [qw/1 2 3/])` is a list of arrayrefs.  It's equivalent to `(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3])`, and the assignment of this to @a is equivalent to: `my @a; $a[0][0] = 'a'; $a[0][1] = 'b'; ...; $a[1][2] = 3;`